Flink State Processor API
I'm using Flink State Processor API to read the state of an application and re-write the state of one of its processor. If this one processor has registered event timers, do I have to read the registered timers and re-register them again when using the State Processor API?
I did use the Flink State Processor API to re-write some state a while back but I did not re-register the timers. Now I'm noticing I'm missing event timers and I'm not sure whether this is happening because I didn't re-register the timers or because of some other issue.
